# When is it appropriate to use semantic elements?

Tags: html, semantics

I do not really understand how (often) I should use semantic elements like `time`, `header`, `footer`.

Do `article`, `nav`, `figure`, `time`, etc just replace `div id="post"`, `div id="navbar"`, `div id="illustration"`, `span id="time"` and, therefore, I should use them only when I need wrap some content for styling purposes or they are something more than that?

Comment: Take a look at this document where they explain how to use the `footer` element: http://html5doctor.com/the-footer-element-update/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General: You should use them so often you can.

If you developing an intranet application, most time no one will care about it.

The Good thing of semantic use is in the public area (Internet)

- A Search engine wants to know about semantic, so it could better understand your page
- A Screenreader can say "This is a Blockquote", "This is a Navigation", "This is a Footer"

Semantic is not for styling a page, semantik is for understanding a page. Blind people don't see your css for example, but a good structured website is better for text to speach and help blind people.

Also take a look at https://schema.org/

> And what about the following example : there is a story with some
>   dates on a webpage. Do I have to put these dates inside time tags?

Yes. Take look at the Mozilla Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

According to it, you can do this:

```
<time datetime="2001-05-15 19:00">May 15</time>
```

You can even do it without time (which is optional according to documentation)

```
<time datetime="2001-05-15">May 15</time>
```

Comment: And what about the following example : there is a story with some dates on a webpage. Do I have to put these dates inside `time` tags?

Comment: Cool, thanks. Also, what do you think about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099551/when-do-i-put-h1-h6-inside-an-header-element? Would you use `header` element? It is related to this question

Comment: @user3790069 if "stackoverflow" in the header of this site here would be a text indstead of an image, it would be a good candidate for `<h1>`. So this said: Headline in Header would be a Headline, which is the same on every page. A specific headline is more content related for me.

Answer (score 1):

A `<footer>` typically contains the author of the document, copyright information, links to terms of use, contact information, etc. The same story aplies for a `<header>`. You **can** use multiple `<footer>` and `<header>` elements in your html file.

The `<time>` element can be used as a way to encode dates and times in a machine-readable way so that, for example, user agents can offer to add birthday reminders or scheduled events to the user's calendar, and search engines can produce smarter search results.

An example:

```
<p>We open at <time>10:00</time> every morning.</p>

<p>I have a date on <time datetime="2008-02-14">Valentines day</time>.</p>
```

Here is a link to the W3Schools page:

[Footer page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp)

[Time page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp)

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: I'm very sorry, this is my first answer so I'm not very good at it yet. Thanks for the feedback though! ;)

Comment: welcome to SO. Your answer is full ok in terms of SO. It was only a hint, developers don't realy like this side, because they sell expensive certificates that are nothing worth in industry and their documentation isn't realy complete. No problems with your answer. Thanks for contributing to SO.